# How to change color to html word inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I need to change the color at the word inside my div. It's filled dinamically, there is a javascript function that read on DB and write through the ID of my div.
I'm trying to color the word INFO (only INFO), without success:

```js
$("div:contains('INFO')").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("INFO", "<span class='green'>INFO</span>"));
});


/* THis is only an example*/

document.getElementById('textLog').innerHTML ="Load[DB]: INFO";
```

```css
.green {
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuLog">
  <div class="log">
   <h3 class="textStyle">Log</h3>
   <div id="textLog" class="silverStyle" name="textLog" required></div><br>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I read all your helps, but anyone didn't satisfied my question, someone went
near to solve it, but the problem was always the same, your examples 
colored only one word, so I changed the reg exp:

```js
$('#textLog').html('INFO start <br> INFO loadDB <br> WARN connection <br> ERROR DB not exist');
changeColor();


function changeColor() {
 $('div:contains("INFO")').html(function () {
     return $(this).html().replace(/INFO/g, "<span       style='color:green'>INFO</span>"); 
   });
     $('div:contains("WARN")').html(function () {
     return $(this).html().replace(/WARN/g, "<span       style='color:orange'>WARN</span>"); 
   });
     $('div:contains("ERROR")').html(function () {
     return $(this).html().replace(/ERROR/g, "<b><span       style='color:red'>ERROR</span></b>"); 
   });
    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textLog" class="silverStyle" name="textLog" required></div><br>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can grab the element that contains the text you want, as you are already trying to do, then use an html replacement for just the word INFO:

```
$('div:contains("INFO")').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace(/INFO/g, "<span style='color: green'>INFO</span>"); 
});
```

Updated Fiddle based on all extra requirements found in comments: https://jsfiddle.net/bL24mw97/

Comment: So this function only if a div contains the words....example: <div>INFO</div>, instead in my case the words is 'injected' by javscript, so doen't run this manner

Comment: You can't color a simple word, you must put it inside something like the span I put in the example, maybe you need to read a little about HTML and CSS works.

Comment: Please look at my fiddle. That colors the single word by replacing the text with an HTML span that is green

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can run the code after the injection of the text. I have updated the fiddle. Have a look. You press the button, text gets injected, and INFO gets colored.

Comment: Based on the latest explanation, I edited my use of replace to use a regex, so that it works for all instances of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
function changeColor() {
  $( "span:contains('Info')" ).css( "color", "green" );
}

document.getElementById('textLog').innerHTML = "<span>Info<span>";
document.getElementById('textLog1').innerHTML = "<span>Info<span>";
document.getElementById('textLog2').innerHTML = "<span>Info<span>";

//This part emulates the data loading
//setTimeout(function(){ 
//  console.log('Data populated....');
//  //when finished you must call the function
//  changeColor();
//; }, 500);

changeColor();
```

```css
.green {
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contains demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="textLog" class="silverStyle" name="textLog" required></div>
<div>TEST</div>
<div id="textLog1" class="silverStyle" name="textLog" required></div>
<div id="textLog2" class="silverStyle" name="textLog" required></div>

</body>
</html>
```

You need to call the changeColor() method to change the color, do it when the function that fill the info finish.

Comment: This one color only the first item ... not all

Comment: This color all row, I asked to color (read title) the word, only the word

Comment: What do you mean as all row? can you be more explicit?

Comment: I mean, this snippet of code, color of green all row: {"eventID":1546,"time":"2017-09-04 14:25:21","level":"INFO","message":"[loadDB] . Instead I need to color the SINGLE word INFO. Thank you for your help, but the solution of the timeout according to me is heavy, can decrease the performance.

Comment: The time out is an example to trigger the function, I don't know when you populate the table, you didn't put this code in your example.  About the color, you can't color a simple word, you must put it inside something like the span I put in the example.